# How to recover my encrypted files?

Tags: 16.04, encryption, data-recovery, ecryptfs

Story:

- I lost Ubuntu GUI (unknown problem).
- Then tried to recover files via Windows, so I could reinstall Ubuntu. But, when mounting `/home` partition to Windows, a malware copied the files into a folder named " " (space) and created a shortcut.
- When I tried to recover my encrypted files through an Ubuntu live CD using `ecryptfs-recover-private`, I got this:

[image]

You may not see the (space) folder, but it's accessible through LiveUSB's GUI.

- Then I managed to rename the (space) folder, but I think I accidentally deleted files: `README.txt` and `Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop`

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy-paste the text instead.

Comment: Based on the terminal output, there is no folder called " ". What were you trying to do there?

Comment: 2.  the malware has copied only the files that appeared in the encrypted /home directory into a folder named with one space. now i managed to rename that folder, so it's a no worry.

Comment: @wjandrea now i just logged in to my ubuntu system in terminal mode (as i said i have GUI issue) and i run Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop file, so i was prompted for passphrase. i entered it, but i got error saying: `Error: Unwrapping passphrase failed [-2]; Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs`

Comment: Oh, you got ransomware! That sucks. Windows malware is a whole other can of worms, so I'm not sure AskUbuntu is the best place to ask for advice. Maybe SuperUser.com would be better.

Comment: Wait, I thought that was CryptoLocker but I might be wrong.

Comment: @wjandrea, no it's not CryptoLocker or sth. but i guess the problem is that home directory path has become like this `/home/Folder12/{username}/{files}`. Where Folder12 is the name i gave for the spaced folder (as i said i solved the space named folder issue). and {files} are **Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop** , **README.txt**, and other hidden folders. So, how i go about decrypting my files knowing that i get that error msg (my last comment) when i run command : `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with file recovery - I would like to share how I managed to do it:

1. Command showing encrypted file directory:

**sudo find /media -type d -name .Private**

2. Command to unlock private directory plus directory shown from command above:

**sudo ecryptfs-recover-private**

(example: sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /media/ubuntu/1efe72f6-86-41e9-9d46 c7b2bb9a1b61/username/.Private)

*I used not an encrypted pass phrase, but password of Ubuntu login and it worked (strangely encryption pass phrase didn't work for me – try both).*

3. After successful attempt directory will be created in /tmp/created folder name by system.
4. to access those files I had to be root:

**sudo se**

5. and to open directory from terminal:

**nautilus /tmp/created folder name by system**

6. to copy desired folders, files had to select them, mouse right click "Copy To..."

Hope it will help someone that are not so skilled with Ubuntu like me :)